# Get the roles associated with a asp.net page

Tags: asp.net

I'm developing a web site and on the web.sitemap i define which roles can access a certain page, is it possible to know on the page which are the role associated to then on the web.sitemap

Comment: Found the answer now I need to create the navigation menu according to the user permissions

Comment: Found the answer to create the menu

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemapnode.roles.aspx) property of the SiteMapNode.  Probably something like:

```
     SiteMap.CurrentNode.Roles
```

Comment: Yep, that was one of the solutions